# Parse response from Consul in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, json

I am using bash to get a value back from Consul, I have the API call working but can't seem to get the parsing down. I have tried regex and also jq but neither seem to work. Below is the results of the API call that I need to parse. I am trying to get the `MTA3NDE5` from it.

How can I get that value from what the API call returns?

```
[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"syncID/master","Flags":0,"Value":"MTA3NDE5","CreateIndex":1951278,"ModifyIndex":1952289}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something simple like `jq -r '.[]."Value"'`

Ex.

```
$ echo '[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"syncID/master","Flags":0,"Value":"MTA3NDE5","CreateIndex":1951278,"ModifyIndex":1952289}]' | 
  jq -r '.[]."Value"'
MTA3NDE5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ echo '[{"LockIndex":0,"Key":"syncID/master","Flags":0,"Value":"MTA3NDE5","CreateIndex":1951278,"ModifyIndex":1952289}]' | \
  grep -E -o '"Value":"[^"]*"' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d '"'
```